# Preventing line breaks in space separated Chinese text in html

Tags: html, css

I have some text in Chinese which has been separated with white space for the purpose of learners. E.g. 我 喜欢 学 中文.

I would like to present this text in HTML, without introducing line breaks within the words. I would also like it to be possible for the text to break between words. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a non-breaking space; `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Unicode Word Joiners (U+2060, HTML Code `&#8288;`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm) to connect characters that should not be broken between lines.

HTML

```
<span>我 喜&#8288;欢 学 中&#8288;文</span>
```

This works, but is not very semantical.

The following is a lot better, because it does not change the actual text (this is good for copy/paste) and you can use CSS and other methods (HTML titles, JavaScript) to format it and make it interactive:

```css
span.chineseWord {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
span.chineseWord:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="chineseWord">我</span>
<span class="chineseWord">喜欢</span>
<span class="chineseWord">学</span>
<span class="chineseWord">中文</span>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code does not break the lines at all, either for spaces or within words. This makes it impossible to display blocks of text. I would like to allow breaking between words, but not within.

Comment: @CarlJohan Ah, now I understand. See modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a no-break space (U+00A0) instead a normal space you can mostly prevent a line break in a specific location where you wish to have some space. (I wrote “mostly”, because browsers do not quite consistently implement no-break space semantics.) But doing so in Chinese text will just make browsers break lines between Chinese characters in positions where no space is used—on modern browsers.

Modern browsers generally implement part of [Unicode line breaking rules](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/), which define that line breaks are generally allowed between Chinese characters, unless prevented by specific rules.

If you wish prevent **all** line breaks within a segment of text, then the most effective way is to slap the tags `<nobr>` and `</nobr>` around it. If you would rather be standards-conforming, at the cost of some loss of functionality, make the segment an element, like `span`, and assign `white-space: nowrap` to it in CSS. If you wish allow line breaks at specific positions inside such a segment, use the (empty) tag `<wbr>` or the U+200B character (which you can include e.g. by writing `&#x200b;`).

More info: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

Answer (score 1):

A few years after this question post, `word-break: keep-all` is finally supported by Firefox 15 and Chrome 44. And it would be what OP want:

```css
.text {
  word-break: keep-all;
  
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">我 家 的 后面 有 一个 很大 的 园 ， 相传 叫作 百草园 。 现在 是 早已 并 屋子 一起 卖 给 朱文公 的 子孙 了 ， 连 那 最 末次 的 相见 也 已经 隔 了 七八年 ， 其中 似乎 确凿 只有 一些 野草 ； 但 那时 却是 我的 乐园 。</div>
```